# Uploading image from cloud page is working upto 3mb but above 3mb - 5mb is not uploading

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi

Cloud page code

```ampscript
    var files = document.getElementById("file").files;
    document.getElementById("spinner-border").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("LoadingMessage").innerHTML = ""
    if (files.length > 0) {
      document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block";
      getBase64(files[0]);
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("LoadingMessage").innerHTML = "Select a picture"
      document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
                                                    );
  
  function getBase64(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function () {
      var fileEncoded = reader.result;
      var base64enc = fileEncoded.split(";base64,")[1];
    
      var fullFileName = document.getElementById("file").files[0].name;
      var fileName = fullFileName.split(".")[0];
      var assetName = fullFileName.split(".")[1];

      
       fetch("https://xxxxxx/yyy", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
        ,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          base64enc: base64enc,
          fileName: fileName,
          assetName: assetName
        }
                            )
      }
           )
        .then(function (res) {
        document.getElementById("LoadingMessage").innerHTML = checked ;
        
        document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
      }
             )
        .catch(function (err) {
        document.getElementById("LoadingMessage").innerHTML = "Failed"
        document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
      }
              );
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) { 
      console.log('Error: ', error);
    };
  }
</script>
```

Process code

```ampscript
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
try {
    var MID = Variable.GetValue('@MID')
    var apiCreds = Variable.GetValue('@xyz');
    var credentialObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(apiCreds);
    var clientId = credentialObj.clientId;
    var clientSecret = credentialObj.clientSecret;
    var authURL = credentialObj.authURL;
  Variable.SetValue("@authURL",authURL);
    
    var jsonData = Platform.Request.GetPostData();
    var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(jsonData);

    
    var base64enc = obj.base64enc;
    var fileName = obj.fileName;
    var assetName = obj.assetName;

    
    var assetTypes = { ai: 16, psd: 17, pdd: 18, eps: 19, gif: 20, jpe: 21, jpeg: 22, jpg: 23, jp2: 24, jpx: 25, pict: 26, pct: 27, png: 28, tif: 29, tiff: 30, tga: 31, bmp: 32, wmf: 33, vsd: 34, pnm: 35, pgm: 36, pbm: 37, ppm: 38, svg: 39, "3fr": 40, ari: 41, arw: 42, bay: 43, cap: 44, crw: 45, cr2: 46, dcr: 47, dcs: 48, dng: 49, drf: 50, eip: 51, erf: 52, fff: 53, iiq: 54, k25: 55, kdc: 56, mef: 57, mos: 58, mrw: 59, nef: 60, nrw: 61, orf: 62, pef: 63, ptx: 64, pxn: 65, raf: 66, raw: 67, rw2: 68, rwl: 69, rwz: 70, srf: 71, sr2: 72, srw: 73, x3f: 74, "3gp": 75, "3gpp": 76, "3g2": 77, "3gp2": 78, asf: 79, avi: 80, m2ts: 81, mts: 82, dif: 83, dv: 84, mkv: 85, mpg: 86, f4v: 87, flv: 88, mjpg: 89, mjpeg: 90, mxf: 91, mpeg: 92, mp4: 93, m4v: 94, mp4v: 95, mov: 96, swf: 97, wmv: 98, rm: 99, ogv: 100, indd: 101, indt: 102, incx: 103, wwcx: 104, doc: 105, docx: 106, dot: 107, dotx: 108, mdb: 109, mpp: 110, ics: 111, xls: 112, xlsx: 113, xlk: 114, xlsm: 115, xlt: 116, xltm: 117, csv: 118, tsv: 119, tab: 120, pps: 121, ppsx: 122, ppt: 123, pptx: 124, pot: 125, thmx: 126, pdf: 127, ps: 128, qxd: 129, rtf: 130, sxc: 131, sxi: 132, sxw: 133, odt: 134, ods: 135, ots: 136, odp: 137, otp: 138, epub: 139, dvi: 140, key: 141, keynote: 142, pez: 143, aac: 144, m4a: 145, au: 146, aif: 147, aiff: 148, aifc: 149, mp3: 150, wav: 151, wma: 152, midi: 153, oga: 154, ogg: 155, ra: 156, vox: 157, voc: 158, "7z": 159, arj: 160, bz2: 161, cab: 162, gz: 163, gzip: 164, iso: 165, lha: 166, sit: 167, tgz: 168, jar: 169, rar: 170, tar: 171, zip: 172, gpg: 173, htm: 174, html: 175, xhtml: 176, xht: 177, css: 178, less: 179, sass: 180, js: 181, json: 182, atom: 183, rss: 184, xml: 185, xsl: 186, xslt: 187, md: 188, markdown: 189, as: 190, fla: 191, eml: 192, text: 193, txt: 194, freeformblock: 195, textblock: 196, htmlblock: 197, textplusimageblock: 198, imageblock: 199, abtestblock: 200, dynamicblock: 201, stylingblock: 202, einsteincontentblock: 203, webpage: 205, webtemplate: 206, templatebasedemail: 207, htmlemail: 208, textonlyemail: 209, socialshareblock: 210, socialfollowblock: 211, buttonblock: 212, layoutblock: 213, defaulttemplate: 214, smartcaptureblock: 215, smartcaptureformfieldblock: 216, smartcapturesubmitoptionsblock: 217, slotpropertiesblock: 218, externalcontentblock: 219, codesnippetblock: 220, rssfeedblock: 221, formstylingblock: 222, referenceblock: 223, imagecarouselblock: 224, customblock: 225, liveimageblock: 226, livesettingblock: 227, contentmap: 228, jsonmessage: 230 };

    var assetTypeID = assetTypes[assetName];

    //authenticate to get access token
    var authEndpoint = authURL //add authentication endpoint
    var payload = {
        client_id: clientId, //pass Client ID
        client_secret: clientSecret, //pass Client Secret
        grant_type: "client_credentials"
    };
    var url = authEndpoint + '/v2/token'
    var contentType = 'application/json'

    var accessTokenRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
    if (accessTokenRequest.StatusCode == 200) {
        var tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
        var accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token
        var rest_instance_url = tokenResponse.rest_instance_url
    }
    //make api call to create asset   
    if (base64enc != null) {
        var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
        var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
        var jsonBody = {
            "name": fileName,
            "assetType": {
                "name": assetName,
                "id": assetTypeID
            },
          "category": {
               "id": 213
          },
            "file": base64enc
        };

        var requestUrl = rest_instance_url + "asset/v1/content/assets"

        var createAsset = HTTP.Post(requestUrl, contentType, Stringify(jsonBody), headerNames, headerValues);
        
    }

} catch (error) {
    Write("<br>error: " + Stringify(error));
}
</script>
```